# TYPO3 extbase news ajax pagebrowser

Tags: typo3, tx-news

TYPO3 6.1

I have applied the ajax for news pagebrowser.
To do that I have added below code in setup

```
news_ajax_list = PAGE
news_ajax_list {
typeNum = 1122
config {
disableAllHeaderCode = 1
xhtml_cleaning = 0
admPanel = 0
debug = 0
no_cache = 1
}
10 = USER
10 {
userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
extensionName = News
pluginName = Pi1
switchableControllerActions.News.1 = list
}
}
```

and my ajax jquery code looks like this.

```
$changeduri = $('.page-navigation .f3-widget-paginator li.next').find('a').prop('href')+'&type=1122';
var uri = $changeduri;
$.ajax({
url: uri,
type :'GET',
success: function(data) {
$('.news .news-list-view .page-navigation').before($(data).find('.news-list-view .ajaxcnt').html());
$('.news .news-list-view .page-navigation').html($(data).find('.news-list-view .page-navigation').html());
$('.news .news-list-view .page-navigation').after("<script type='text/javascript'>$('.f3-widget-paginator .next').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();renderUrl();});</script>");
}
});
```

The Ajax pagebrowser works very well.
But my problem is the url to detail page is not linking to detail page, instead its linking to current page (list page) itself.
I have printed `{settings.detailPid}` in `Partials/List/List.html` and that was empty for ajax loaded news list items. And it was correct for initial loaded news list items

What was the problem here? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out yourself, your settings are empty. You should add the settings for news to your TypoScript:

```
news_ajax_list = PAGE
news_ajax_list {
  [...]
  10 = USER
  10 {
    [...]
    settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
    # (over)write detailPid if it is not set/set differently in your news configuration
    settings.detailPid = 31
  }
}
```